# Why is type deduction on const char[] different to const char *?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constants

In the first call, when I pass a `char const []` into a template function with a parameter of `T const a`, `T` is deduced as `char const *` which is reasonable because `const` refers to the decaying pointer.

However, when the parameter type is changed to `T const & a`, `T` is deduced as `char[7]`. From the point of view above, why doesn't the `const` qualify the whole array type?

```cpp
template <typename T>
void show1(T const a) {
     // input is const char *
     // T is char const *
     // a is char const * const
}

template <typename T>
void show2(T const & a) {
     // input is char const [7]
     // T is char[7]
     // a is char const (&)[7]
}

int main() {
    const char s[] = "asdasd";
    show1(s);
    show2(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why doesn't the `const` qualify the whole array type

Because for [array type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array),

(emphasis mine)

> **Applying [cv-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) to an array type (through typedef or template type manipulation) applies the qualifiers to the element type**, but any array type whose elements are of cv-qualified type is considered to have the same cv-qualification.
>
> ```
> // a and b have the same const-qualified type "array of 5 const char"
> typedef const char CC;
> CC a[5] = {}; 
> typedef char CA[5];
> const CA b = {};
> ```

That means when `T` is `char[7]` `T const` leads to the type `char const[7]`, then `T const&` (i.e. `a`'s type) is `char const (&)[7]`.

On the other hand, when you pass the array `s` with type `const char[7]`, the array is considered as const-qualified too. So given the parameter type `T const&`, `T` is deduced as `char[7]` (but not `char const[7]`).

Comment: thanks your empahsis, the seocnd sentence seems doesn't relate.

Comment: @BAKEZQ I think it's related, just in opposite direction, *when elements are const-qualified then the array is considered as const-qualifed*.

Comment: based on the second sentence, If the deduction goes like this？  1:  `char const [7]` considered as `const(char[7])`. 2 : since the paramete type is `T const &` , `T` is deduced as `char[7]`.

Comment: @BAKEZQ Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because arrays are non-copyable and non-assignable in C++.

So in calling `show1`, the `const char[]` type decays to a `const char*`. The language permits one implicit conversion per parameter at a function call site.

With `show2`, you are passing by reference - no copy or assignment is required, so pointer decay does not occur.

Comment: why const in the second case doesn't qualify `char const [7]` like `char const[7] const`

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
void show(ParameterType a) {
}

show(expression);
```

Compiler uses `expression` to deduce `T` and `ParameterType`. `T` and `ParameterType` are different if `ParameterType` contains qualifiers like `const`.

If `ParameterType` is neither pointer nor reference (case of your show1, `T const`), type of `T` is type of `expression` without `const`, `volatile` and reference. So `T` is type of `const char *`. `ParameterType` (type of `a`) is `const char * const`.

If `ParameterType` (`T const &` in your show2) is pointer or reference (but not reference like `T&&`). First ignore reference, which gives results `T const` (same as `const T`). Second match type of `expression` (`const char []`) to `const T`, so `T` is `char []`.

For more information, [Item 1 of Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html) is exactly what you want. The rule is more complicated then which I described here but very important.

Comment: I was thinking the same way, following this rule, the `T const` 's `const` should qulify the whole array type which is `char const []`. In ordinary view, the `const` in `const char []` qualifies the type `char` like the first code, so leads to my confusion. The quotation in the accepted answer seems can explain this.